# Cannot figure out how to add tables for each user in discord server, no error is given

Tags: javascript, discord.js, node-sqlite3

Been trying at this for a few hours, can't seem to figure out a solution. It's probably right in front of me, but who knows. I'm trying to insert a user id for every user who is not currently in the table, problem is, it doesn't work. No errors or anything, it just doesn't create the information.

```
client.on('ready', async () => {
  db.serialize(function() {
    db.each("SELECT id id, name name FROM users", function(err, row) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      var u, user;
      for (u in client.users.array()) {
        user = client.users.array()[u];
        if (!row.id.toString().includes(user.id.toString())) {
          db.run('INSERT into users VALUES(?,?)', user.id.toString(), 100);
        } else {
          console.log('User already exists!');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Does it log  `console.log('User already exists!');`

Comment: No it does not log to console.